# How to annotate that a trans-unit contains e-mail text?

Tags: email, xliff

If a trans-unit contains text that will go into an e-mail, the line endings need to be CRLF (\r\n). This has to be taken care of when importing/exporting XLIFF files from and to a database. Is there a suitable attribute to set on such a trans-unit? What about `extype`?

XLIFF specification: http://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/v1.2/os/xliff-core.html#trans-unit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XLIFF follows XML whitespace rules, which means that you'll need to make sure to set `xml:space="preserve"` -- otherwise, the line breaks will be normalized away.  If you need to store anything beyond that, `extype` might be a possible place, although I don't think that attribute is consistently supported in tools.